# Search text file

Tags: vb.net, text-search

I am new to programming and I wonder how to make a search in a text
as follows.

I have a text with the following content

> I won today as if he knew the truth Today I am lucid as if to die And
>   had no more kinship with things

What I want and search this text has the word

> truth if you

I wanted to store a string starting word of "truth" until the words had meaning the string would be

> Today I am really lucid as if you were to die and had no

and omit the rest of the text.

Already I tried to search the position of the word "truth" but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.

If you want to find a word inside a string you can use the function INSTR

```
Dim Position as integer = 0
Dim SampleText as String = "I won today as if he knew the truth Today I am lucid as if to die And had no more kinship with things"
'
Position = INSTR(SampleText, "truth")
if Position > 0 Then
  'matched
  msgbox("Word 'truth' found starting at position " & Position)
Else
  'not matched
  msgbox("Word 'truth' not found in text!")
End if
```